# Can I retrieve account uid using Chef User resource?

Tags: chef-infra

Is it possible to retrieve some account details using Chef `user` resource?

I can do for example

```
u = user 'myuser' do
  action :manage
end
```

Then I would like to use `u.uid` or something to retrieve the `uid` of the user.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef store all users in the node object under the key `etc`.

This tree is populated by ohai at start of run, so to update it and be able to access `node['etc']['passwd']['myuser']['uid']` you have to ask ohai to run the `etc` plugin again like this (quoted from [ohai documentation](http://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#id3):

```
ohai 'reload_passwd' do
  action :nothing
  plugin 'etc'
end

user 'daemonuser' do
  home '/dev/null'
  shell '/sbin/nologin'
  system true
  notifies :reload, 'ohai[reload_passwd]', :immediately
end

ruby_block 'just an example' do
  block do
    # These variables will now have the new values
    puts node['etc']['passwd']['daemonuser']['uid']
    puts node['etc']['passwd']['daemonuser']['gid']
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow...this looks pretty advanced. This reveals a completely new world to me. Good to know. What I can I also do  is `uid = `id -u #{node['jenkins']['master']['user']}`.delete("\n")`. That will we give me the `uid` or `""` in one line of Ruby. Must be faster too. What would advantage of doing `ohai` thing and not quick and dirty in one line of Ruby? What would you recommend?

Comment: On first run it'll be probably quicker,on next run you'll got through all the provider code to get the user, information which has already been gathered by ohai at startup, using notifications means the ohai reload will be done only if the user change, so there's 0 computing time in next runs

Comment: And the ruby code in recipe will be done at compile time and not at converge time. So at first run it will be evaluated before the user is created and will return nil